# Multiple Where Clause in Eloquent & Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, octobercms

Trying to do a multiple select statement with eloquent.

used the `Blog::where()`
... function, and included an array in it.

```
$matchThese = ['title' => post('title'), 'slug' => post('slug')];
 return Blog::where($matchThese)->get();
```

When tested it returns an empty value even for matching inputs, database table names correctly written

Model extends October CMS Model, so all eloquent methods in laravel are include. Blog Model Below

```
<?php namespace Andre\Blogroutes\Models; 

use Model;
use ModelNotFoundException;

class Blog extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;
    public $table = 'blog';

}
```

Comment: please show your blog model

Comment: update in your post please. not in comment

Comment: check my answer below and let me know if you still have the problems ?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following queries are exactly the same:

```
$matchThese = ['title' => post('title'), 'slug' => post('slug')];
return Blog::where($matchThese)->get();
```

and

```
return DB::table('blog')->where('title', '=',post('title'))->where('slug','=', post('slug'))->get();
```

if one worked and others didn't that means your `Blog` model is not actually targetting the right table `blog`. You should add the following line to you `Blog` model and see if the old query works:

`protected $table = 'blog';`

Also inside your controller, do not forget to add:
`use App\Blog;`

on top of it. Give the old query a roll and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this:

```
DB::table('blog')->where('title', '=',post('title'))->where('slug','=', post('slug'))->get();
```

Comment: your table name **andre_blog** or **blog** in database ?

Answer (score 0):

The $table variable must be **protected** not **public**

```
public $table = 'andre_blog';
```

to

```
protected $table = 'andre_blog';
```